# A word for a reshaping/change/rebalancing in value/priority?

Tags: word-request

You could say this happened to a temptation as it got closer in time.

> Tying yourself to a mast is a solution for the **?** in the appearance of a temptation as it gets more immediate.
>
> There is a set of ratios in how much we want things, but as things change, these ratios change or a **?** happens to these things. Their seeming values reorganize.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to say? Perhaps include a sample sentence that would potentially include this word. Give us more of an explanation so that we can give you a better fit.

Comment: Reorganizing; Juggling; Ammending...

Comment: Hmm.. For your second example sentence, I would look up synonyms for **[revaluation](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/revaluation)**. Reappraisal? Reassessment?

Comment: The proposed sentences are very awkward but I think an appropriate word is reevaluate or some synonym. See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/reevaluate

Comment: I can only think that **weak** is the best fit for the first sentence, otherwise **readjustment** might fit both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is a play on Homer, The Odyssey, Book 12.

> ...Then I plugged the ears of
>   each of my friends, and they tied me hand and foot and stood me
>   upright in the mast housing, and fastened the rope ends round the mast
>   itself.

The beauty of Odysseus is that he was far from the *moral* hero. He simply **had** to hear the Siren's song and was not interesting in passing the channel *unless he did*. I am not sure what the *one word* for that may be, but the approximate definition is: "*selfish fulfillment of a desire in an ostentatious way.*"

> There is a set of ratios in how much we want things, but as things
>   change, these ratios change or a ? happens to these things. Their
>   seeming values reorganize.

**Paradigm Shift** *(noun)*

- 1- a fundamental change in approach or underlying assumptions.

The order of words would need to change to fit Paradigm Shift in there; maybe remove the final, "...happens to these things."